# Misaligned top tag icon in activity tab on profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, top-tag

I recently noticed a UI bug in the user activity page. If you have not earned all of the available privileges (e.g. you have less than 25k reputation) and you have earned a tag badge in your top tag, and you have your profile set to displaying your `Next Privilege`, you will see this happening:

[image]

This is only a minor bug, but it's just something I'd like to put out there and get fixed for the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: I'm not seeing this; which browser?

Comment: @Shog9 both Chrome and Safari for Mac. You're not seeing it on your profile because you need to have your profile page set to displaying your `Next Privilege`.

Comment: I'm not seeing it on *anyone's* profile. Got an example?

Comment: Yes, [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Ah, there we go. Can't have earned all the privileges, has to have earned a badge in their top tag (or top tags, for the Profile tab).

Comment: @Shog9 I'll edit my question to show this, should I do anything else?

Comment: Naw; should be a trivial fix - the style for vertical centering just got dropped during a recent bit of refactoring. I've filed this with the design team; thanks for the report!

Comment: No problem - when it's fixed, can you `status-complete` this?

Comment: Yep, I'll circle back when I hear something.

Comment: @Shog9 it's fixed - please update with `status-completed`?